# unable to create another new android activity without Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have downloaded android theme and trying to adding new activity further.

using Android Studio 3.0.1 / API 27.

I am trying to add new page by duplicating existing activity which did not have Action bar (screen shot here) [No Actionbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuAqX.png)

I could see the new page has action bar (screenshot here) [with Actionbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dinFe.png)

in my styles.xml file has added Noaction bar settings.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Even try to create empty activity, it shows the action bar. I couldn't be found any other run time code for the settings. I want load the activity using fragment while the button click as per my customize design.

since I couldn't create new activity without Action bar, I stuck in this stage.

it is downloaded theme and comes with no action bar settings. couldn't add any further activity without that?

I have seen all existing method which are already questioned in the forum, but seems it is not relate to anything other than styles.xml content.

Any idea? why this not working

Comment: updated the answer..update if it works..

Comment: please feel free to update if it works..

Answer (score 0):

In the activity which is having actionBar use this code in `onCreate()`

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

It will hide your actionBar

Comment: Hi.. I dont have such a line in my existing activity... but how this to manually add each activity?

Comment: just add this line in the existing activity ..nothing else it will hide your actionBar.. @sankarnatarajan

Answer (score 0):

Apply same them from manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

It will work definitely.

Comment: If I use this, I have syntax error getting. this is my manifest code.
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".design.CleanUpListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".design.ImmediateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".design.MainActivity">

Comment: I may need to add every line for each acitivity. But my existing theme didn't have like any kind of code. But this problem in adding any new xml activity

Comment: @sankarnatarajan share with me screenshot of manifest file and project structure of your application.

Write this style in your style.xml file.
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: Hi.. this is my code of style.xml...
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

Comment: however, I have added the theme name in one of the layout file and I couldn't see the action bar. But surprisingly, i couldn't get any action bar in new created layout... Not sure what is the issue caused. however, thanks for your effort..

Answer (score 0):

I used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and `getSupportActionBar().hide()`  but it doesn't work. And i find this way!

For No action bar Activity you just **copy from a No_action_bar_Activity** from some where else. For me I just create a Basic Activity android provide and delete the tool bar. Or you can find it on Github.

Do the same for ActionBar_Activity
I think it is a bug on **API 27**